# Speeding up Joins with Indexes

Tags: sql, performance, join, indexing

I understand that using indexes can help speed up joins of two or more tables. The following example joins two tables, emps and depts, using their shared department_id column:

```
select last_name, department_name 
from emps join depts 
using(department_id);
```

My question is: would indexing the department_id column on one of the two tables speed up this query, or would I have to create an index on both department_id columns from both tables in order to see an improvement in performance?

Comment: Indexing on one of the tables would benefit the query.  Presumably `depts(department_id)` is a primary key, so it already has an index.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The two tables would naturally have an index on `department_id` already, as this should be the `depts` primary key and the `emps` foreign key.

In your query, it is rather unlikely that the indexes will be used, though. Why should the DBMS bother to scan index trees when it's finally about all records to read? Simple sequential full table scans and then a join on hashes for instance will usually be much faster.

Let's look at another example:

```
select e.last_name, d.department_name 
from emps e
join depts d on d.department_id  = e.department_id
where e.first_name = 'Laura';
```

Here, we are only interested in few employees. This is where indexes come into play. We'll want an index on `emps(first_name)`. Then we'll know the employee record, the `department_id`, and we can access the associated `dept` record.

But saying this, we notice that we use the index to look up the table record to look up the `department_id`. Wouldn't it be faster to get the `department_id` right from the index? Yes it would. So the index should be on `emps(first_name, department_id)`.

The `depts` primary key is `department_id`, so this column is indexed, and we can easily find the `depts` record with the department name.

But we can ask the same question again: Can't we get the name right from the index, too? This leads us to covering indexes that contain all columns used in a query.

So, while

```
index idx_emps on emps(first_name, department_id)
index idx_depts on depts(department_id)
```

suffice, we can get the query still faster with these covering indexes:

```
index idx_emps on emps(first_name, department_id, last_name)
index idx_depts on depts(department_id, department_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always index pk and fks to reduce blocking and contention while the DB enforces consistency and integrity.

I'd also recommended explicit joining, not with `USING`. Too much convention and magic there :)

Comment: What kind of "magic"? It's perfectly readable and boilerplate-free.