# Best way to merge 3+ tables in SQL

Tags: python, sql

I have encountered a situations that it takes a long time when I tried to merge multiple tables together. I am aware of two SQL line that will work but I don't know which one is better or whether there is any difference between them.

SQL1:

```
SELECT a.code,a.date,b.varaible1,c.varaible2 \
FROM TABLEA a,TABLEB b,TABLEC c\
WHERE a.date = b.date\
AND a.code = b.code\
AND a.date = c.date
```

SQL2:

```
SELECT a.code,a.date,b.varaible1,c.varaible2 \
FROM TABLEA a\
JOIN TABLEB b\
on a.date = b.date\
AND a.code = b.code \
JOIN TABLEC c\
on a.date = c.date
```

so is there any difference between the two? or it depends?

Comment: You will need to add indexes to the columns you are trying to join against (i.e. `TABLEA.code`, `TABLEB.code`, `TABLEA.date`, `TABLEB.date`, `TABLEC.date`) - your second join has a typo, I think you meant `a.date = c.date`?  See [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50857254/speeding-up-joins-with-indexes), [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53139003/how-does-indexing-improve-performance-when-joining-two-tables), also [thread on joining three or more tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083676/understanding-how-join-works-when-3-or-more-tables-are-involved-sql)

Comment: yes you are right metatoaster. great catch. I have corrected the typo.